# Just bad convention or problematic? Brackets in Java

Tags: java, conventions

I taught myself Java and for reasons I can't remember I've always written brackets as

```
void method()
{
    if(true)
    {
        //code
    }
    else
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

When all the examples I see are

```
void method(){
    if(true){
        //code
    }else{
        //code
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of the reason it's done like it is and is there any reason to change the way I write it? I think it's easier to read.

Comment: This is not a question for Stackoverflow. The second variant is mostly used because it saves some lines of codes

Comment: IMHO readability is the same but less lines makes 2 option better

Comment: It's all just a matter of preference. Personally I like the latter way (but with spaces before the braces), because it's a bit more compact, but this really is just a matter of preference (and/or your company's coding standards, if applicable).

Comment: Learn both styles, and follow the style set out by your boss, company, instructor, etc... The key is for all folks working on the same project to use a consistent and reproducible style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those "there is no right answer"

The way you indent your code is called the [Allman Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style)

While the other style is [Kernel Normal Form (KNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Normal_Form)

Answer (score 2):

The examples you use follow the style Sun suggests, which is a variant of what is known as K&R style. But it doesn't matter, except insofar as code is nicer to read if you're consistent within a project. But it's not a big deal.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Answer (score 1):

While both are valid and accepted styles, the second is more common in examples (web, books, etc) simply to save space.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you avoid the first format if you port Java projects to JavaScript, you'll be fine.
In JavaScript, if you miss a semicolon, the compiler attempts to insert it for you.
As you might guess, this can lead to debugging-hilarity at times. Usually, it's semi-sane at detecting when not to insert a semicolon at the end of a line, but rather than learn all edge-cases, just don't do it.

But for Java, *knock yourself out*.
Your compiler is going to scream at you if you don't end a statement, so it's never going to get confused about what is an assignment and what is a control block.